# How to change an image in RecyclerView locally using drawable

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to change the image in a `RecyclerView` with a local drawable image. So in the project the `RecyclerView` is getting data from a local database, when a boolean column gets true, it should change into a tick. My item view looks like this.

[image]

And when the column is true, that clock symbol changes to tick. Here is the code which I tried:

My Adapter code:

```
public class HawbListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HawbListAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<HawbLists> hawbLists;
    private DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

    public HawbListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HawbLists> hawbLists) {
        this.context = context;
        this.hawbLists = hawbLists;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.hawb_list, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.Hcode.setText(hawbLists.get(position).getHawbCode());
        holder.name.setText(hawbLists.get(position).getName());

        if (hawbLists.get(position).isTick()) {
            holder.timeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_right);
        }

        //Picasso.get().load(hawbLists.get(position).isTick()).into(holder.timeImage);

        //holder.timeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_right);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return hawbLists.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView Hcode;
        private TextView name;
        private ImageView timeImage;


        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            Hcode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hawbCode12345);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_hawb_list);
            timeImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeImage);

        }
    }
}
```

even when I'm using this

```
if (hawbLists.get(position).isTick()) {
    holder.timeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_right);
}
```

and one of the items is true, it is still showing the same clock (wait) symbol, but If I use this:

```
if (!hawbLists.get(position).isTick()) {
    holder.timeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_right);
}
```

then all of them regardless of true or false turn into tick mark. Unable to figure out where I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: Add the else part and set the non checked image inside it .

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (hawbLists.get(position).isTick()){
     holder.timeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_right);
} else {
     holder.timeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_not_ticked);
}
```

Do you know about the concept of recycling? Look at your list in the device and see how many rows you have! Now add up one (as swap view) and it's all the views you have. It means no matter how many entries you have (`hawbLists.size()`), all of them are created/recycled when you scroll. So you have to consider all the possible cases of your item children. Because otherwise a recycled `view` won't change the `view` state and likely will show irrelevant behavior.